# Textures loading error(JS Animation)

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js

**Intruduction:**
I am writing a simple animation with **JavaScript** and **PIXI.js**.

**How it's working**:
I paint textures in new places and delete it in old places by every step.

**Problem:**
Sometimes i get these results(some textures are not displayed and CPU loaded on 50%)
http://itmages.ru/image/view/2649716/a5ae37b5

**But** if i updating the page i can get normal results (not always) and CPU loaded on 2-3%
http://itmages.ru/image/view/2649736/ca696082

**Code**

!)function **animate** does one step of animation

There are 3 versions:

**1)**

```
anim();
    function anim() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(anim);
            animate();
        }, 40);
    }
```

**2)**`setInterval(function() {requestAnimationFrame(animate);}, 50);`

**3)**`setInterval(animate, 50);`

I **loading pictures** with that function:

```
function presets()
{
    unit_texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('/assets/unit_2.png');//('/images/unit_2.png')
    shell_texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('/assets/shell.png'); //('/images/shell.png')
}
```

**unit_2.png** is about 377 **Bytes** and it's resolution is **(19 x 20)**
**shell.png** is about 30 **KB** and it's resolution is **(200x200)**

**After loading i use these textures to make sprites** (PIXI)

```
function Unit(id, x, y, energy, hp)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.energy = energy;
    this.hp = hp;

    this.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(unit_texture);
    this.sprite.width  = 2 * 50;
    this.sprite.height = 2 * 50;

    this.sprite.anchor.x = 0.5;
    this.sprite.anchor.y = 0.5;

    this.sprite.position.x = x;
    this.sprite.position.y = y;

    stage.addChild(this.sprite);
}
```

At every step i **delete** all **old** Unit objects and **create** **new** Unit objects.
(I **can't** **just** **move them** because of organizaion of my system).
I think the biggest trap here is making sprite many times, but i could not fix it yet.

Comment: looks for me like an loading problem... can u provide more code?

Comment: does it say something in the console? like image reached maximum dimensions or something?

Comment: Console is empty. Also i compressed pictures, but it doesn't helped (lags still there).
By the way, Unit texture almost always is ok. (small size). But i need good quality textures.

Comment: Yes, do you use preloading?

Comment: Thanks, delueg. You guided me to the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PIXI.Texture.fromImage** function is **asynchronous**.
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/2620-settexture-doesnt-always-use-preloaded-images/ 
Possible **solution** of this problem **is here**:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/7674-load-textures-synchronously/